# NFC NFD Normalize in Photoshop Javascript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, cjk, photoshop-script, unicode-normalization

I am using Mac OS. Since Mac OS treat Korean as UTF-8-MAC not just UTF-8.

So the Korean letter is broken when using javascript.

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/196zg.png)

I figured it out that it is related to NFD NFC, i guess.

So I managed to use this script on shell using applescript.

do shell script "echo " & (한글 as text) & "|iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8"

It appears all right.

But I don't know how to do this in Javascript without normalize method.

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Here is full script that getting filename from documents and then make textlayer with that filename.

```
      if ( documents.length > 0 )
  {
    var originalDialogMode = app.displayDialogs;
    app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR;
    var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
    preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
  }
    try
    {
        var docRef = activeDocument;

  // Now create a text layer at the front
        var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
        myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
        myLayerRef.name = "Filename";

        var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

  // strip the extension off
        var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
        if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
            fileNameNoExtension.length--;
        }
        fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");

        myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension;

  // off set the text to be in the middle
        myTextRef.font = "NanumGothic";
        myTextRef.position = new Array( 50, 1450 );
        myTextRef.size = 8;

  // alert test
        //alert(docRef.name);
        //alert(fileNameNoExtension);
        //alert(myTextRef.charset);
        //alert(myTextRef.encoding);
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        // An error occurred. Restore ruler units, then propagate the error back
        // to the user
        preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
          app.displayDialogs = originalDialogMode;
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Related: [What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346453/)

Comment: I don't think this is possible using photoshop script as it's still limited to ECMA v3. You might have to pre-process your text using javascript before sending it to photoshop.